# Trying to change first char element in string array

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to programming, and I was trying to write a program that rewrites any input from the user to be in pascal case.

Working with strings is mostly straightforward. However, I ran into an issue, and one that does not have an easy fix looking through the Internet. Getting -every- element in a string array to be lowercase is easy enough, but making sure that the first char element in an element of a string array to be uppercase is pretty tricky.

I'm asking here instead of just checking the solution (It's a question to a course that has a solutions packet) if there is a solution within the code I wrote up.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write words that you would like to be in pascal case.");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            var inputLower = input.ToLower();

            var inputLowerSplit = inputLower.Split(' ');

            for (var i = 0; i < inputLowerSplit.Length; i++)
            {
                var write = inputLowerSplit[i].ToCharArray();

                Char.ToUpper(write[0]);

                Console.Write(write);
            }
        }
```

Line 14, where Char.ToUpper(write[0]); is, is where I am having the issue. So far I just get the string input where it's all forcibly lowercase and without spaces, which is fine, but the first letter of each word is not uppercase like how I am expecting the code to run.

Looking online does not yield any response. Is it possible within the code I wrote up or do I just need to take on a different approach? Felt like I was on to something.

Comment: .NET strings are immutable; you can't change their contents. Instead, split the string in half (a one char substring for the first char, and and an N-1 length substring for the rest). Upper case the first substring, lower case the second string and then concatenate the two strings. Make sure you consider the null, empty and one character cases

Comment: load write into a StringBuilder, change its first letter then call ToString() on the SB

Comment: Hi, thank you for the responses. Both approaches worked and helped, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the user is entering a `string` containing multiple words and you want to capitalise the first letter of each word and make everything else lower case. In that case, you should convert the entire `string` to title case first, then split it. The `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` method can be used for this, e.g.

```cs
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var words = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input).Split(' ');

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words));
```

With the input below, that code produced the subsequent output:

```
hello WoRlD goodBye
Hello
World
Goodbye
```

That uses the invariant culture but you can use whatever culture is appropriate. You could even incorporate that functionality into one or more extension methods that mimic `ToUpper` and `ToLower`:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToTitle(this string source)
    {
        return source.ToTitle(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public static string ToTitle(this string source, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(source);
    }

    public static string ToTitleInvariant(this string source)
    {
        return source.ToTitle(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

You can then just do this:

```cs
var words = Console.ReadLine().ToTitle().Split();
```

Note that there's no need to specify to split on spaces because `Split` will split on whitespace by default.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to assign the char you want

```
write[0] = char.ToUpper(write[0]);
```

This will return the char as uppercase in the position you want.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the question in its entirety because Pascal case means not just the first character upper case but all other characters lower case. This only addresses the first part of that.